# I want to get a Mobile version of my drupal site working

Tags: multi-sites, theming, subsites

I am trying to setup what I would call a multisite configuration on my local development server, which currently looks like this.
I'm using Xampp in a windows environment so my root is Xampp\htdocs. Any site I'm working on is created under a folder here; for example, for \devsite this gives me the following Drupal structure: \sites\all\themes\devsite.

In my browser, I can go to *http://localhost/devsite*, and it launches my Drupal site. If I go to *http://localhost*, I get redirected to the Xampps install site.

My hosts file is altered to include these two entries.

- 127.0.0.1 devsite.com
- 127.0.0.1 m.devsite.com

Browsing to http://devsite.com/devsite, or http://m.devsite.com/devsite now launches my site.

I copy the content of the \devsite\sites\all directory to the \devsite\sites\m.devsite.com directory (I make some CSS changes so it would be obvious), and setup a \devsite\sites\sites.php file with these entries.

```
$sites = array(
  'devsite.com' => 'all',
  'm.devsite.com' => 'm.devsite.com',
);
```

If I browse to either hostname, both load the site configuration which is in All. I can't seem to get it to load anything within m.devsite.com? I've tried copying the settings.php file into each stucture which produces an error message. I've tried renaming All to devsite in folder and sites.php but then I get a blank page when browsing.

Do you have any idea on how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Have you reviewed: http://drupal.org/node/26357#comment-267473 or http://drupal.org/node/37177#comment-68606 ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned whether you're using D6 or D7, D6 needs to have multisites all symlinked together (see the way that Aegir does it) whereas D7 uses the sites.php that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to create a new theme on the subdomain right?

I got this working recently on a CentOS server; all I had to do was added a folder in the sites directory called "m.mydomain.com" with a copy of the settings.php file from "sites/default" with the following line appended:

```
$conf['theme_default'] = 'fusion_mobile';
```

Come to think of it, I should probably include the other settings.php file to keep things organized, but that was all I needed for the basic functionality you're describing (beyond the DNS setup). I didn't have to create a sites.php file, or copy the entire file structures across.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Omega](https://drupal.org/project/omega) for that. It's based on CSS media queries.

Comment: I'm pretty sure she/he's looking for a multi-site solution.