# Mobile browser to be assigned different background

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get my site to operate differently depending on if the browser is a phone or a computer etc... I understand that this is most likely done using the sites.php file but I've been unable to get this working, and have an open question on SO about it.

[Broad Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/i-want-to-get-a-mobile-version-of-my-drupal-site-working)

This question is a little more specific and is to tied me over while I battle the broader issue out. I would like to remove the current background image when a mobile browser turns up. I thought something like the following would do it (same CSS file)

```
body {
 background-color:blue;
}

@mobile {
 body {
 background-color:green;
 }
}
```

but this doesn't appear to make any difference when using my HTC desire using Dolphin.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) for that.

It's based on CSS media queries.

Answer (score 1):

two things:

1. Why not keep things neat by creating a new stylesheet and putting the css media rule in the .info file?
2. If you're thinking of @media queries, that syntax isn't right.. maybe you're thinking of `@media handheld { /* rules */ }`

have a look here - http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

regardless, I know the question referenced the HTC desire but I thought I'd warn you that iPhones ignore `@media handheld` and use `@media screen` instead, so you need to do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { /* rules */ }
```

Courtesy of Smashing Magazine - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/